# Error while creating site from specific template

Tags: site-template

I am creating a site under a site collection using specific template and it throws

> Unexpected error occured

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: You need to provide more details, like ULS logs (http://samirvaidya.blogspot.se/2012/03/where-are-sharepoint-uls-logs.html) and what template your are using, does it have publishing enabled? As much details as possible

Comment: First port of call would be ULS logs and check whether the web you used for the template has any features enabled that are not available in site collection?